# "else" is not working on my Jquery code with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have a section on my website, with Q/A blocks. If we click on question title (h3), it must appear answer hidden under the question.

So on the right side of question title, we have arrow down, and arrow up. As you might understand, it must be appeared arrow down when question is "closed", and arrow up when question is "open".

```js
    $("img.up").hide();

    $(".question h3").click(function(){
    
     var b = $(this);
    
     var a = b.parent(".question").children(".answer");
    
     a.slideToggle();
    
     if(a.css('display') == 'block'){
         b.children("img.down").hide();
         b.children("img.up").show()
        } else {
         b.children("img.up").hide();
         b.children("img.down").show()
        };
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
     <h3>
      А я могу ездить на Mercedes S-Class без прав?
       <img src="img/icons/down.png" alt="" class="down">
    <img src="img/icons/up.png" alt="" class="up">
  </h3>
  <div class="answer">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit aspernatur, consectetur amet mollitia quasi sint provident, totam ad facere quia cumque magnam quisquam culpa praesentium aperiam qui voluptatem maxime corporis.
  </div>
    </div>
```

Code works on first click, and ignores all next clicks. Else is not working. I know that it is easy but... Sometimes you can't do such a simple things

Comment: Try putting in more tests, you are assuming that a lot will be successful...for example when you assign to a, why not check the return of (".question") before trying to get children?  Also test that (".answer") is what you expect before using it to get css

Comment: works on the code snippet using the code you provided. Maybe it's an issue related to some other js code on the page that is conflicting?

Comment: It appears to work, but the `<img>` tags are actually not toggling, because `slideToggle` does not change the `display` property of the `div`'s css - it just changes its height.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the state of `.answer` elements css display attribute, before calling the `.slideToggle()` method and use this stored state to hide/display your arrow images:

```js
$("img.up").hide();

$(".question h3").click(function(){

    var b = $(this);

    var a = b.parent(".question").children(".answer");

    // Store isVisible state for answer element before ..
    var isVisible = a.css('display') == 'block';

    // ..you call slideToggle()
    a.slideToggle();
     
    if(isVisible){
        b.children("img.down").hide();
        b.children("img.up").show()
    } else {
        b.children("img.up").hide();
        b.children("img.down").show()
    };

});
```

```css
img {
  width:1rem;
  height:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
    <h3>
        А я могу ездить на Mercedes S-Class без прав?
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/154963/1313159889.png" alt="" class="down">
            <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/154969/1313159942.png" alt="" class="up">
    </h3>
    <div class="answer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit aspernatur, consectetur amet mollitia quasi sint provident, totam ad facere quia cumque magnam quisquam culpa praesentium aperiam qui voluptatem maxime corporis.
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for storing this is that `slideToggle()` will immediately sets the display of the answer to block, regardless of the animation (either to close, or open). For this reason, you need to determine if the answer is visible before animating the answer div (via the call to `slideToggle()`), so that you can use that state to control which up/down arrow is shown/hidden.

Here's an updated [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ouq9m1t/7/) for you to see :)

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the problem, which is that the `img` tags don't toggle. Your `img` tags aren't visible, so (as far as I can tell) your code works just as well as the original poster's code.

Comment: @ChrisLear thanks for pointing that out! just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem.
I have added

```
 $('h3 img').toggle();
```

which will toggle the image accordingly.

> Below is the working code.

```js
$("img.down").hide();

$(".question h3").click(function(){

    var b = $(this);

    var a = b.parent(".question").children(".answer");

    a.slideToggle();

   $('h3 img').toggle();
    
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
    <h3>
        А я могу ездить на Mercedes S-Class без прав?
            <img src="img/icons/down.png" alt="down" class="down">
            <img src="img/icons/up.png" alt="up" class="up">
    </h3>
    <div class="answer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit aspernatur, consectetur amet mollitia quasi sint provident, totam ad facere quia cumque magnam quisquam culpa praesentium aperiam qui voluptatem maxime corporis.
    </div>
</div>
```